# How do I give the Spinner in Gingerbread the same UI as in ICS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I have a news app which implements

1. ActionBarSherlock
2. ViewPagerTabIndicator
3. PullToRefresh

I want to use Navigation Mode List  in the Action Bard Sherlock to switch between news sources, but it seems that the ViewPager with the view pager indicator conflicts with the navigation mode in the ActionBarSherlock; so I added my own spinner (custom view) in the ActionBarSherlock but the problem is that its UI in **Gingerbread** doesn't look the Same as the UI of the built-in navigation in ActionBarSherlock.

My Question is simply how do I apply the UI of the navigation in ABS to the Spinner ?

Comment: 1 problem snap = 1000 problem words

Comment: I'm not asking about a problem in the code (That's a separate question I posted already with code snippets), I'm asking about how to change the style of the default spinner in GB to be like ICS.

Comment: holoeverywhere library might be usefull , not sure, worth a look ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are conflicts of ViewPagerIndicator and ActionBarSherlock, so you should take a look at your project again to see what's the issue.

To answer the question: Although it is not recommended, you can use ActionBarSherlock's `IcsSpinner` instead of `Spinner` to get the same look on Gingerbread devices.

Comment: Well ActionBarSherlock works with ViewPagerIndicator but the Navigation Mode in ABS doesn't, I've seen many others having the same problem and some questions here too, but without answers.

Comment: IcsSpinner did the job regardind the UI, but it's no-longer clickable, I think the actual conflict is between IcsSpinner and ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I'm sorry that the answer does not solve the problem in your case. Nevertheless it is the correct answer to your question, you should accept it.